# window location and innerHtml replace

Tags: javascript, html

This code is for the purpose of replace content inside a div using `?sub=1` as a trigger.
I'm pretty new to the javascript world, I created this code but I'm missing something, and I can not figure out what
If sub is  =1, change the content inside the div to "other content"

```js
var url = new URL(window.location);
var sub = url.searchParams.get("sub");

if(sub == 1) {
    document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = "<span>Something</span>\n<div>Something</div>"
}
```

```html
<div id="element">Content</div>
```

Comment: Where in your html document is the javascript, respective to the div element, you are trying to change?

Comment: Open up the developer console and look for the error(s)

Comment: `sub` will be a string so you should change the if to `if(sub === "1") {`

Comment: @epascarello That's not the problem, the above code works as well. `1` is converted to a string upon computation.

Comment: @BogdanM. I know how it works.... pointing out a better way of doing the check. And I closed the question with that the issue is....